# Method definition and naming conventions in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I come mainly from a C# background, and currently I am learning Ruby on Rails. Reading through railstutorial.org, I see a lot of code like this (this one is Listing 10.49):

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :valid_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  .
  .
  .
  def edit
  end

  private

    def get_user
      @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    end

    # Confirms a valid user.
    def valid_user
      unless (@user && @user.activated? &&
              @user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end
end
```

Now, what I learned is to make methods as granular as possible, and method names as informative as possible. The method here, `valid_user`, checks if a user is valid, and then redirects to the `root_url` if it is not valid.

In this case, what I would do is to either rename the method to `redirect_to_root_if_not_valid`, or instead of using a separate method, just use something like `user.valid?` if I need to check, and then redirect wherever it is needed.

To me the method name and also the method info is misleading, it doesn't just confirm a valid user, it also redirects somewhere if a user is not valid.

Is this something that is weird to me because I am coming from a C# background, or is this just another way of doing things that I am not accustomed to?

Comment: I agree, these names are not descriptive either, but they are just a naming sample from tutorial - you can use more descriptive names if you want. For instance, I would name the `valid_user` method `ensure_user_valid`, but that is just my preference.

Comment: you can name it as just  `validate_user`

Comment: I'd expect method `valid_user` to return a user that is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the methods are named poorly. First of all I would pull the check for `activated?` into a guard clause in the `User` class since a non-active user can *never* be authenticated in my opinion:

```
class User < ActiveRevord::Base
  # ...

  def authenticated?(...)
    return false unless activated?
    # ...
  end
end
```

Then, I'd rename the methods to `assign_user` and `ensure_user_authenticated`, extract the authentication check into a separate method and use `@obj.try(:method, args)` instead of `@obj && @obj.method(args)` in the controller:

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :assign_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :ensure_user_authenticated, only: [:edit, :update]

  # ...

  private

    def assign_user
      @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    end

    def ensure_user_authenticated
      redirect_to root_url unless user_authenticated?
    end

    def user_authenticated?
      @user.try(:authenticated?, :reset, params[:id])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You are entering the uncanny valley of "what's the best way to do x", and in the ruby community people love that. Anyway, I'll give yet another *opinion* on how to refactor your code:

Create an `authenticated?` and filter methods [and put them in the `ApplicationController`, you'll be going to reuse it probably | or not, it depends on wether the logic is shareable]. Also, I like to define an `user` method and writer instead of using filters to achieve [almost] the same behavior.

```
class ApplicationControlller < ActionController::Base
  before_action :restrict_access_to_authenticated_users

  private

  def restrict_access_to_authenticated_users
    redirect_to root_path unless authenticated?
  end

  def authenticated?(u = user)
    u && u.activated? && u.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id])
  end

  attr_writer :user # I use this so you can overwrite the user without using the code beneath
  def user
    @user ||= User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  end
end
```

Comment: Good point. You'll (almost) always want to put authentication logic into the application controller.

Comment: I agree, that this way of accessing user is better than initializing it in `before_action`. I believe, `before_action` should only contain some "cross-cutting" functionality that is easily can be plugged in or unplugged, depending on requirements (changing the functionality, but not affecting the workability of other code). However, you cannot unplug `find_user` as most likely some code will break after that.

Comment: In @hattenn's code user is looked up by email (and you've changed that). So I believe it's something quite specific to password resetting and should be in `PasswordResetsController`. `params[:id]` can also contain some reauthentication token, I am not sure, but anyway most likely it does not make sense outside of `PasswordResetsController` as well. So I'd suggest to move that all back to the `PasswordResetsController`.